# How to Display the Contents from StreamReader directly on Notepad?

Tags: c#, streamreader, notepad

Is there a way to display the contents from memory directly in a Notepad window?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to read the contents of a notepad window? Is that file saved already on the machine?

Comment: Also, Please take some time to phrase your question properly. Tag it properly as well. "To" is not a right tag.

Comment: kindly rephrase your question its not clear what you want

Comment: Do you want notepad to reflect the lines you've read? Is that your goal?

Comment: Yes, can I open notepad to show some in-memory text?

Comment: No, you can not. Open it for a file.

Comment: @RashmiPandit check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613576/how-to-open-text-in-notepad-from-net/14295249#14295249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-click on the file, making sure the association is set to Notepad.

If you want Notepad to show it without saving it to disk, you can open an instance of Notepad, get the handle for the window, then write the text directly into there.  You will need to use Windows User APIs to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that I understand your question. If the file already exists on the machine you can execute the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "notepad.exe", "[PATH]\[FILE].txt");
```

If not then save the file locally and then run the above code.

Comment: In case the file does not exist on the file-system, is it possible to open a notepad to display some in-memory text?

Comment: Why not save the file to a temporary directory?

Comment: Your question states you are READING A TEXT FILE, hence all answers telling you to open it in Notepad directly are correct.  If this is not the case, change your question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to save the file and open it in notepad, however there are at least two other ways.

1. Open Notepad then copy what you want to the clipboard, then using DDE force Notepad to paste.  This is bad, because it potentially overwrites what the user may have been doing in the clipboard.
2. The second way involves getting a window handle to the notepad Edit control, then doing a WM_SETTEXT to the window.  This will not, however, work across privilege boundaries (such as for apps that run as administrator, but notepad runs as a normal user).  This also involves getting down to Native level and doing P/Invokes.  Not exactly an easy method.

Frankly, it's just easiest to save it to a file and load it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need notepad to show some contents (which is in memory)?

If you are using winforms, you could put it in a textbox.
Sorry, if I have not understood your question correctly.

Comment: I dont need to. Just wanted to know if that is possible. I am doing some RnD using Console App

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to MrEdmundo's answer that the [Isolated Storage](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx&ei=gzCZSdWIM8-n-gbynciOCQ&usg=AFQjCNFhdAspR8wKUGaXdjS3j9I_WqBCMA&sig2=IVo0nGlRijCc0IQsd5I6fQ) is the right place to store the temporary txt file for Notepad.

Comment: Depends on the size of the file. Isolated storage has pretty low default limits for file sizes (1MB I believe).