# How to open text in Notepad from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I click a button on a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) form, I would like to open a Notepad window containing the text from a TextBox control on the form.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this out:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test.txt", textBox.Text);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\test.txt");
```

Comment: Yes, don't force Notepad on a user that has her own preferred text editor.

Comment: I got answer from you. Thanks you. :)

Comment: If used more than once, then file will overwrite itself, so its not like it will continue making new copies leading to garbage buildup. Make the path in a system temp folder.

Answer (score 55):

You don't need to create file with this string. You can use [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) to solve your problem.

**Usage of NotepadHelper class:**

```
NotepadHelper.ShowMessage("My message...", "My Title");
```

`NotepadHelper` class code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Notepad
{
    public static class NotepadHelper
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowText")]
        private static extern int SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

        public static void ShowMessage(string message = null, string title = null)
        {
            Process notepad = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe"));
            if (notepad != null)
            {
                notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
                    SetWindowText(notepad.MainWindowHandle, title);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                {
                    IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
                    SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*References (pinvoke.net and msdn.microsoft.com):*

SetWindowText: [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowText.html) | [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx)

FindWindowEx: [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html) | [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx)

SendMessage: [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html)  | [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This is far more cleaner way of doing stuff. Does not leave garbage data on the disk.

Comment: @kmatyaszek It seems like your reference links are broken, or maybe the site is down? Would you mind updating them, if possible?

Comment: @Shredder the site pinvoke.net is online but I added references to msdn site too.

Comment: this is just great!  it can be noted that it will reinstantiate notepad with each calling.  thanks

Comment: this function does not working windows 11. it can't edit notepad. Do you have any think for this problem?

Comment: Spellunking around other applications, and poking their window handles, is not supported. I'm surprised it worked at all in Windows 10, and i'm not surprised it breaks at any time. Notepad's internal implemenation details are subject to change at any time, for any reason, without any notice.

Answer (score 5):

Save the file to disk using [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllText("path to text file", myTextBox.Text);
```

Then use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to open it in notepad:

```
Process.Start("path to notepad.exe", "path to text file");
```

Comment: @Shredder - I don't understand your question. When the file is open in notepad, it will be locked.

Comment: When i wrote your answer like that.

string s = txtNum.Text;
Process.Start("notepad.exe", s);

that text appear only header.not open in notepad.
Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For non ASCII user.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
```

Based on **@Peter Mortensen** answer

Add **CharSet = CharSet.Unicode** to the attribute for supporting Unicode characters

Answer (score 0):

I was using the NotepadHelper solution until I discovered it doesn't work on Windows 11.  Writing the file to disk and starting with the default text editor seems to be the best solution.  This has already been posted, but I discovered you need to pass UseShellExecute=true.

```cs
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, value);
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new() { FileName = path, UseShellExecute = true };
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
```

I write to the System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() folder and run a cleanup when the application exits - searching for a unique prefix pattern for file names used by my app.  Something like this:

```cs
string pattern = TempFilePrefix + "*.txt";
foreach (string f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.GetTempPath(), pattern))
{
    File.Delete(f);
}
```